# Receiving authentication failed error while running sonar with Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, database, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Receiving authentication failed error while running sonar (3.7.3) with Mysql.I am able to run sonar using h2 database of the same.So i dont believe it's due to the wrong user name and password.
And how to get the detailed log while running sonar.Right now i am not able to see more details about this authentication error in logs

Comment: Wrong place for such a question Have a try over at the SuperUser sister page.

Comment: Post full console details.